# ASP.Net Master Page Sidebar display after Login (keeping it displayed whilst logged in)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, master-pages, sidebar

I have the following sidebar on my master page. It is not a part of any ContentPlaceHolder.

```
<div runat="server" visible="false" id="menuAccountMembersDiv" class="leftCol">
    <asp:Menu ID="menuAccountMembers" runat="server" StaticSubMenuIndent="16px" Visible="false">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Resources/x.png" 
        NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="x" ToolTip="x" 
        Value="b647ce4e-5c7f-400c-a921-ec7902494f26"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Resources/y.png" 
        NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="y" ToolTip="y" 
        Value="y"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Resources/sarahhunkin.png" NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" 
        PopOutImageUrl="~/Resources/z.png" Text="z" 
        ToolTip="z" Value="z"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Resources/a.png" 
        NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" 
        PopOutImageUrl="~/Resources/apop.png" Text="a" 
        ToolTip="a" Value="a"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

I initially hide it. But I would like to display it and keep it displayed after logging in. Using the standard web application login page. I tried the following:

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Menu MenuAccountMembers = (Menu)Master.FindControl("menuAccountMembers");

    MenuAccountMembers.Visible = true;

    Control menuAccountMembersDiv = (Control)Master.FindControl("menuAccountMembersDiv");

    menuAccountMembersDiv.Visible = true;
}
```

I am not sure to to interact with the div tag, as there is no Div object. In any event, this does not display the sidebar with the menu

**EDIT**:
I ended up adding the following code to the master page itself.

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Control MenuDiv = this.FindControl("menuAccountMembersDiv");
            MenuDiv.Visible = true;

            Menu AccountMenu = (Menu)MenuDiv.FindControl("menuAccountMembers");
            AccountMenu.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have access to the controls by ID. There is no needing to use FindControl() methods. You can use just menuAccountMembersDiv.Visible = menuAccountMembers.Visible = true; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for setting the visibiliy directly on your div based on authentication status

```
<div runat="server" visible="<%# Page.User.IsAuthenticated %>" id="menuAccountMembersDiv" class="leftCol">
```

that way you don't need your `LoginUser_LoggedIn` method and the menu will show/hide on every load depending on the user is logged in or not

And remember to remove the `Visible="false"` from your `<asp:Menu>` control, if the outer `div` is hidden, nothing inside it will be shown anyway.

Comment: And, of course, he needs to call DataBind() in codebehind for code you provide ;)

Comment: @Dima true! IMO in WebForms apps a call to DataBind() is more the rule than the exception though :)

Answer (score 1):

A div tag is a HtmlGenericControl class. To get access to this class import namespace System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; and use something like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = Master.FindControl("menuAccountMembersDiv") as HtmlGenericControl;
if(div != null)
{
    div.Visible = true;
}
```

Or you can move your menu to UserControl and hide or show just use ID of your UserControl.

Hope it will help you with your question.

Comment: and since HtmlGenericControl inherits from Control, you code is basically no different than what he had already.

Comment: I think it's not good practice to cast all to base class )) In this case it doesn't matter but in another it does. This is my point.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the runat="server" tag in the menu's Div tag, you can reference it directly in code...

```
menuAccountMembersDiv.Style.Item("Display") = "none";
```

or

```
menuAccountMembersDiv.Visible = False;
```

Comment: enuAccountMembersDiv.Style["Display"] = "none" in c#

Comment: I think he tries to get access to that control from Page that has Master page.